# Which is proper to use in this sentence "is" or "are"?

Tags: word-choice

Defending against these class actions [are or is] very expensive and require the expenditure of significant amounts of time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

"is" is correct since the act of 'defining' is singular.

Comment: Also: "... and require**s** ..."

Answer (score 0):

"Defending against these class actions" is a gerund phrase which could be easily substituted by "it", so "is" needs to be used here. Also, following the same rule, the verb "require" must change to "requires" .